# has_many through relationship with conditions based on relationship table (Rails 2.3.5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a relationship that is as follows.

```
companies_employee.rb
belongs_to :employee
belongs_to :company
validates_presence_of :role

employee.rb
has_many :companies_employees
has_many :companies, :through => :companies_employees

company.rb
has_many :companies_employees
has_many :managers, :through => :companies_employees, :source => :employee, conditions => {:role => "Manager"}
has_many :owners, :through => :companies_employees, :source => :employee, :conditions => {:role => "Owner"}
```

My problem is that when it checks the conditions, it tries to find the role column in the employees table, but the role column is in the companies_employees table.
Is there a way to make it use things in this table for the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
has_many :managers, :through => :companies_employees, :source => :employee, conditions => ["employees.role = 'Manager"]
has_many :owners, :through => :companies_employees, :source => :employee, conditions => ["employees.role = 'Owner"]
```

Comment: That has the exact same problem, it still tries to look up the row column in the employees table, when what I want is to look up the role column in the :companies_employees table.

Comment: Well, change the employees.role to companies_employees.role.